# Download Sentinel-2 images of specific country

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2

I can use SCP plugin for QGIS and download a rectangle shape area but is there any way to download for a specific country or district?

Comment: You would need a very big disk.

Comment: Disk space is not a problem!